# Flutter deep link with uni_link and go_router not working correctly on Android

Tags: android, dart, deep-linking, flutter-go-router, gorouter

I am using the [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) package together with the [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) in my app and my deep links are opening the app. I used this method to retrieve the deep link:

```
  Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      final initialLink = await getInitialLink();
      // Parse the link and warn the user, if it is not correct,
      // ...
      context.go('someLocation');
    } on PlatformException {
      // Handle exception by warning the user their action did not succeed
      // return?
    }
  }
```

That is working perfectly fine on iOS. However on Android when opening a Deep Link, it automatically takes the link as a `path` and `go_router` tries to navigate to the location, which fails because the deep link is not an actual location. I am creating the location from the deep link, but there is also other information in that link so the **link should not be the exact path**.

It is also calling `initUniLink` and going to the location (context.go(`someLocation`) in the code above is called. But simultaneously go_router fails and the `errorBuilder` is triggered, since the path didn't match any location.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is Android using the link as path right away? How can I avoid that?

My only idea was to catch the link inside the routers `redirect` and check if it is a deep link. If so, I could simply navigate the user to the HomeView. And `initUniLink` will work anyway. But that feels wrong, since `go_router` shouldn't even be called to push to the location from the deep link.

Any idea? Happy for every help. Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score -2):

```
**<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:label="Your App">
    <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="your_scheme"
            android:host="your_host"
            android:pathPrefix="/your_path_prefix" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**
**Configure Deep Links in AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
final goRouter = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: goRouterKey,
  navigator: Navigator(onGenerateRoute: goRouter.goRouterFunc),
  initialLocation: "/",
  errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, String location) {
    // Check if the location is a deep link, and navigate accordingly
    if (isDeepLink(location)) {
      context.go('HomeView');
    } else {
      // Handle other errors
    }
  },
);
```

**Evaluate go_router Necessity:**
Assess whether go_router causes conflicts with Android deep link handling. Consider using default Flutter navigation if go_router is not essential.

**Custom Redirect Handling in go_router:**

Comment: not really an answer to the question. `go_router` is essential for me and your cusotm redirection code is simply the code version of the idea that I stated in the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).